# Download button is not working for every images on website

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have one Website where i am loading multiple images from source and after every image i have shown one button.when i am clicking on download button only first image is downloading with many time.I want to download every images which is available on website.Can Any one please help.

this is code where i am loading images and rendering to website.but after one image next download button is not working for next image.it is only working for first one.

```
const btn = document.getElementById('downloadImage');
const imgurl = url;

        let new_html ='';
        new_html += '<tr>';
        new_html +='<td>';
        new_html +='<img  src="'+url+'" class="center">';
        new_html += '<a href="'+url+'" download>download</a>';
        new_html +='</td>';
        new_html +='</tr>';
        $('#List').find('tbody').append(new_html);


btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('ABC')
  downloadImage(imgurl);
})

function downloadImage(url) {
  fetch(url, {
    mode : 'no-cors',
  })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
    let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    a.href = blobUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
  })
}
})}}
```

Any one can help so that every download button can work for every specific image which is loading from source.

Comment: There's some missing information. For example, how is `btn` declared, and what is `imgurl`?

Comment: please check code once.i am taking images from firebase and showing on my website.after every images download button is there you can shown on code i have added button after every image.and i want that when my user click on download button of image that image can download only once.this code is downloading images but only first image is downloading of multiple time.i want to download every image on clicking download button only once.can you help me.

Comment: to begin with it's not very perfectly clear how everything is supposed to work.. anyway trying to remain inside those shady borders, as long as you just want to allow a user to download something once only, in terms of UX, the quickest approach could be to just have a click event handler to any element responsible of downloading the single file, that will just make the clicked element disabled or pointer events none and leave the logics of download to the browser instead of doing the fetch yourself

Comment: It would of course require the download attribute on your anchor elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?retiredLocale=it#attr-download